# Breed of chicken

Tags: chicken

My question has to deal with breed of chicken not really cooking, but my friends insist that those rotisserie chicken you often find sold at costco are overcooked and chicken not fresh thus the meat just "falls apart".

The chicken used for rotisserie's are of a different breed from the chicken you normally found at "Asian" Supermarket in NYC.

Anyone know what are the breed of chicken normally at at asian supermarket? The meat is more lean, than the rotisserie chicken.

Comment: What does the first paragraph have to do with your question?

Comment: I seriously doubt that there is a single breed used in all Asian supermarkets, and that there is another single breed used in all costcos.

Comment: What makes you think that this is a difference in breed, as opposed to a difference in preparation, cooking method, etc?  I'd find that much more likely unless you can back up your implied assertion with pictures or other references.

Comment: @logophobe, because the chicken at costco have the consistency of purdue chicken, and they advertise that purdue has their own breed of chicken.

Comment: @logophone, forgot to mention, that a picture won't do any good, cause they look alike, but when you bite into the chicken, the texture is difference. Try ordering a roast chicken from a chinese resturant.

Comment: I assume you mean Perdue (not Purdue), and that's not a breed, it's a farming/distribution company. Is that what you actually mean by "breed"?

Comment: @Aaronut Perdue does make the claim on [their website](http://www.perdue.com/faqs.asp) that Perdue chickens are a unique breed. "The PERDUE® bird is our own breed and one of its natural characteristics is meatiness. In fact, our birds have been bred to possess a greater meat-to-bone ratio than any other available breeds."

Comment: @MCHam I don't see why that would be attributable to the breed of chicken, rather than how it's prepared. I'll accept that Costco purchases from a single supplier but there's probably wide variation between smaller Chinese restaurants who buy from different poultry suppliers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would argue that if the meat 'falls apart' it would be due largely to the cooking process used, and very little due to the choice of breed.

As other commentators have stated, there's probably a variety of chicken breeds used in Asian markets across the US - whether any of them use the same as Costco is anyone's guess.

My guess is that a rotisserie-chicken at a high-volume operation like Costco would error on the side of caution for food-safety reasons and cook it longer than it needed to